# G++ cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: g++

Compile command:

```
g++ -c main.cxx -o test_bot --std=c++17 -I/usr/local/include -lTgBot -lboost_system -lssl -lcrypto -lpthread
```

On local machine all is OK, but on prod it is erroring:

```
-bash: ./test_bot: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Local machine arch: `x86_64`, on prod `aarch64`

Comment: Please share the architecture of the CPUs locally and on production, respectively!

Comment: `x86_64` and `aarch64` are different cpu architectures with different machine code. Is it possible that you simply compile the source code directly on the target machine? Or do you want to cross-compile your code on `x86_64` local machine? Then you will need an according toolchain including a cross compiler and the target architecture libs on your local machine. Did you try to search the web for `arm GNU toolchain` or similar?

Comment: There is a problem, I didn't found how to compile it for `aarch64`, all my attempts ended with compiling for `x86-64`

Comment: Please edit your question and explain what you have tried so far and where you got stuck! As a new Stackoverflow member you will find some hints for writing a good question here: [ask]